# Why does Main not wait for all threads to evaluate in asynchronous program?

Tags: c#, asynchronous

@Dan Dinu's answer from a previous question regarding asynchronous programming in C# provides a useful minimal example, which I have adapted as follows:

```
// From https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14455293/how-and-when-to-use-async-and-await

using System;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace minimal_async_await_SE
{
    internal class Program
    {
        public static async Task MyMethodAsync()
        {
            Task<int> longRunningTask = LongRunningOperationAsync();
            // independent work which doesn't need the result of LongRunningOperationAsync
            // can be done here
            Console.WriteLine("Independent work");
            //Call await on the task
            int result = await longRunningTask;
            Console.WriteLine(result);
        }

        public static async Task<int> LongRunningOperationAsync()
        {
            await Task.Delay(1000);
            return 1;

        }

        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            MyMethodAsync();
            Console.WriteLine("Returned to Main");
            //Console.ReadKey();
        }
    }
}
```

If I uncomment line 32, I get the following expected result:

```
Independent work
Returned to Main
1
```

Basically:

1. `Main` calls `MyMethodAsync`
2. `MyMethodAsync` calls `LongRunningOperationAsync`
3. `LongRunningOperationAsync` then calls `Task.Delay`, but `await`s it which suspends further evaluation of the enclosing method `LongRunningOperationAsync`, returning control to the caller, namely `MyMethodAsync`.
4. **`MyMethodAsync` prints out `"Independent work"`.**
5. `MyMethodAsync` attempts to assign the result of `LongRunningOperation to` result`but`await`s it, suspends evaluation of the enclosing` MyMethodAsync`, and returns control of the program back to` Main`
6. **`Main` prints out `"Returned to Main"`**
7. `Task.Delay(1000)` in `LongRunningOperationAsync()` completes
8. A new thread is  spawned, In the caller of `LongRunningOperationAsync` (`MyMethodAsync`) the integer `1` is assigned to `result`.
9. Evaluation of `MyMethodAsync` completes, and **`MyMethodAsync` prints out the value of `result`**
10. Control is given back to `Main`, which suspends evaluation until the user enters a key via `Console.ReadKey`

Firstly, is my understanding of how this program evaluates correct? Secondly, why is it that when I comment `Console.ReadKey`, I get the following unexpected result?

```
Independent work
Returned to Main
```

Does the `Main` method not wait for all threads to get evaluated before exiting out of the program? Why or why not?

Comment: Declare your main method as `async Task`

Comment: The simple answer is, because it doesn't! It isn't designed to. You can fix this by having `static async Task Main(string[] args)` and then awaiting `await MyMethodAsync()`

Comment: Both of your answers make sense, but that begs the more philosophical question: what calls `Main` itself?

Comment: The compiler bootstraps the application to call main as the entry point in various situations, its a language feature and well documented. However I think your main issue is with the async and await semantics and pattern, it's probably best to start your learning journey there

Comment: Why would it? If you have an async Task and you don't tell the runtime to wait for it, it doesn't ... And once the `Main` method comes to an end, the whole  programm ends. If you want to wait for your task, you have tell the runtime accordingly. Ie make the `Main` method `async` as well and use `await MyMethodAsync()` ...

Comment: Link to the docs: [Main() and command-line arguments](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/fundamentals/program-structure/main-command-line)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The answer to your question "Why or why not?" is complex, but could be answered with a better understanding of a `Task`.

A `Task` is not a thread. Many tasks can run on a single thread, and a single task can be run on multiple threads.

A task is more like an event, that will trigger a scheduler to run some code on whatever thread it has available at the time (ignoring some complex issues of continuation)

So your question could be re-phrased to "why does my program not listen to all events and block execution until all have fired?". The answer to that question probably kept 1 or 2 designers of the TPL (Tasks) awake at night, and ultimately they decided that the effects of this decision had the potential to do some serious harm to other types of applications

The designers of TPL did give us a way around this (a few editions of C# later) which is async Main methods. In your case it would look like this:

```
    static async Task Main(string[] args)
    {
        await MyMethodAsync();
        Console.WriteLine("Returned to Main");
    }
```